# OCCI : How to set BusyOption to NOWAIT when using certificate for external authentication

Tags: c++, oracle, connection-pooling, occi

I have an application that is using the OCCI Oracle instant client 12 to connect to the DB. Previously, we were using user name and password for authentication then we switch to use certificate external authentication. This has worked without changing to the application source code.
Now we moved to use the Oracle instant client version 21_7. After the change, the authentication doesn't work without a change. As per [this example](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lncpp/accessing-oracle-database-using-cplusplus.html#GUID-3F1B3810-8FE3-46EB-92D0-49C077B92261), when creating a connection pool for external authentication, pool type parameter should applied using "USES_EXT_AUTH" and "HETEROGENEOUS" as shown below.

```
StatelessConnectionPool *scp = 
      env->createStatelessConnectionPool(
         username, passwd, connectString, maxCon, minCon, incrCon, 
         StatelessConnectionPool::PoolType(
            StatelessConnectionPool::USES_EXT_AUTH|
            StatelessConnectionPool::HETEROGENEOUS));
```

With above change of using correct pool type for creating connection pool, it seems it would work only if the "BusyOption" is set to "**WAIT**" or "**FORCEGET**". It does not work when the BusyOption is set to "**NOWAIT**". If the BusyOption is set to "**NOWAIT**", below exception would throw:

```
ORA-24459: OCISessionGet() timed out waiting for pool to create new connections
```

My question is, how to get the certificate external authentication to work with BusyOption "NOWAIT"? Is it not supported for External Authentication?

Comment: What exactly is throwing that error?  Is ext auth really the problem? What I think you might be seeing is the result of  Session Pool "fix" in 18c to respect NOWAIT correctly.  Now if NOWAIT is used, and the app wants a connection but the pool needs to grow (because all connections are already being used), then the session-get call will fail.  In older versions it would wait until the pool had grown and then return a connection.  The new behavior reduces locks and lets users who want a connection/error without delaying the app do just that. See Oracle bug 26045612

Comment: From oracle doc https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lncpp/statelessconnectionpool-class.html#GUID-C0591485-F818-4AC0-9875-ED245BDABCA6 " minConn and incrConn values are considered only in these HOMOGENEOUS pools.", does this mean we can't set pool size for connections so NOWAIT is not applicable?